# XSLT Transformation cdata section

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to do xslt transformation for an input xml with cdata section.i would like to remove some part of the message and retain others.Please find attached input and expected output xml.can you please help me.Any content with in message-body tag should be the output of xslt and it will have a cdata section.

```
    Input XML :

    <ns2:esb-message xmlns:ns2="http://messagev2.esb.company.com/">
        <header>
            <identity/>
            <message-date-time>2017-01-10T13:19:39</message-date-time>
            <esb-environment>DEV</esb-environment>
        </header>
        <body>
            <request>
                <esb-metadata>
                    <user-id>Cube</user-id>
                </esb-metadata>
                <message-body>
                    <web:Custom xmlns:web="http://webservices.com/">
                        <aAddRoot>1</aAddRoot>
                        <aUseResultEncoding>1</aUseResultEncoding>
                        <aXMLInput><![CDATA[<rate lob="15">
        <heading>
            <program parent_id="1001" program_id="1" program_ver=""/>
        </heading>
    </rate>]]></aXMLInput>
                    </web:Custom>
                </message-body>
            </request>
        </body>
    </ns2:esb-message>
```

Expected output:

```
                <web:Custom xmlns:web="http://webservices.com/">
                    <aAddRoot>1</aAddRoot>
                    <aUseResultEncoding>1</aUseResultEncoding>
                    <aXMLInput><![CDATA[<rate lob="15">
    <heading>
        <program parent_id="1001" program_id="1" program_ver=""/>
    </heading>
</rate>]]></aXMLInput>
                </web:Custom>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where exactly are you having problems with this. Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:web="http://webservices.com/">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="aXMLInput"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="//web:Custom"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```